# How to to make a provider for a Remix app?

Tags: remix.run

I would like to create a "provider" that could simply be added to a Remix app like this:

`root.tsx`:

```
import { MyProvider } from "my-package";

export async function loader() {
  return "bla";
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <html>
      <head>
        ...
      </head>
      <body>
        <MyProvider />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

This provider would fetch scripts and style sheets, and add them to the document (not sure how to do that yet, React Helmet doesn't seem appropriate).

My question is: how to do these fetches server-side?

I tried to create a loader inside the `MyProvider` component, but I discovered that the `useLoaderData` hook was returning the data of the loader from the parent component! ("bla" in the above example.)

For the moment, I:

- call a function `getProviderData` in the loader function of `root.tsx`
- give the data returned by this function to `MyProvider` through `useLoaderData`
- create the script and style tags in `MyProvider` (so they'll be in `body` instead of `head` but it shouldn't be an issue).
- add a `meta` tag using the `meta` function

`root.tsx`:

```
import { getProviderData, MyProvider } from "my-package";

export const meta: MetaFunction = () => ({
  'my-data': 'xxx',
});

export async function loader() {
  const providerData = getProviderData();

  return defer(providerData);
}

export default function App() {
  const { providerData } = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();

  return (
    <html>
      <head>
        ...
      </head>
      <body>
        <MyProvider providerData={providerData} />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

It's a lot of manual steps and it's quite convoluted for the consumer of my package.

Could someone think of a better solution?